# Jira nFeed plugin returning blank values

Tags: jira

I have an nFeed plugin on my Jira instance that I'm trying to learn to use. I have a select list in my create screen and I have it configured to JNDI. When I go to my select list, it has 3 options (how many rows in my table), but they're all blank.

Here is my query

```
 SELECT p.PRODUCT_NAME, p.PRODUCT_ID FROM NIRD_Product_Groups p
```

and my key is 0

I have native filter checked and the display template is {1}

anyone hae an ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like probelm with your SQL query.
- Have you tried to enable the Debug mode of this nFeed field to figure out if ther is any error raised ?
- What type of database are you pulling data from ? Depending on its type you probably need to put double quotes around your attribute and table name in your query.
- You set the key as 0, which refers to the PRODUCT_NAME attribute. Would not it be safer to set the key as PRODUCT_ID ? This sounds more accurate to me.
- Have you tried to test this configuration on a different web browser ?

If you need further help, Valiantys is providing free support on its plugin here : https://jira.valiantys.com